# Flutter PageView with Consumer not updating on add/remove page, unless manually flipped to a diffrent page

Tags: flutter

I have a Consumer of my ApplicationState which extends ChangeNotifier. When itemsMerged is updated via a listener I expect my PageView to update. However, when I remove or add an item there is no update until I flip to another page manually.

```dart
    Consumer<ApplicationState>(
            builder: (context, appState, _) => PageView.builder(
              controller: _controller,
              itemCount: appState.itemsMerged.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GamePage(match: appState.itemsMerged[index]);
              },
            ),
          ),
```

How do I make the PageView update on add/remove?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that if you are using a StatefulWidget in your PageView you need to assign each StatefulWidget a unique key when you build the PageView.

More info here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc